# Habitat - Renderings vs Sublayouts

Tags: presentation, helix

All of the common CSHTML views in Habitat are in a folder called `Sublayouts`.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Project/Common/code/Views/Common/Sublayouts

However, I'd usually call these `Renderings` vs `Sublayouts`, because they're Razor views. Specicifally, I'd call them `View Renderings`. This is backed up in the Content Editor, where these items exist as Renderings:

[image]

Is there some terminology difference in Habitat that I'm not aware of? Or is it just confusing naming within the Habitat codebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Helix documentation View Renderings are considered Sub-Layouts.

**As layouts and sub-layouts (in MVC defined as View Renderings) typically control the overall page design and therefore contain very site or project specific mark-up, they belong in Project layer modules.**

http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/layout/layouts.html